# Stripe payment logic in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm trying to having users fill out a form, and then pay to submit it. Once the users pays I need rails to change a boolean from a separate model to true.

Here is my charges controller, exactly from the docs.

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
def new
end

def create
  # Amount in cents
    @amount = 2900

    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      :email => current_user.email,
      :card  => params[:stripeToken]
    )

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :customer    => current_user.email,
      :amount      => @amount,
      :description => 'OneApp',
      :currency    => 'usd'
    )

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to charges_path
  end

end
```

Comment: you can use `after_create` callback and do what you want

Comment: There is no "Charges" model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the creation of a `Stripe::Charge` is enough for you, it's as easy as retrieving the instance of the model you want to modify in your `create` method and set your boolean there.

Say, for example, you want to set a `subscribed` boolean for the current user, so in your create method you add:

```
current_user.subscribed = true
```

or, say you want to set a `paid` boolean on an `Order` model instance, then in the create method you add:

```
order = Order.find_by_some_way(:some_way => the_value_you_want)
order.paid = true unless order.nil?
```

If you need to konw when the money has actually been transferred, you have to ask Stripe. There's a good gem to integrate Stripe's webhooks:

https://github.com/integrallis/stripe_event

Anyway, if you are trying to know whether a user bought something or not, I'd suggest to wait for the actual transfer notification, because the Charge doesn't actually tell you whether you got the money or not.

Comment: So your saying in side the Stripe::Charge params have something like @app.boolean = true ?? or just inside the actual create method?

Comment: I don't have access to current_user in my charges controller

Comment: I was just making some examples, I can only guess what you are trying to achieve and how your project looks like, that is up to you after all.

Comment: I added this in my create method user = User.find(current_user) user.payed = true, but yet still wont change the boolean to true in the database.

Comment: just a silly question: do you also do `user.save`? and it sounds strange that you cannot just do `current_user.payed = true`. which class does `current_user` belongs to?

Comment: @Dileet I have facing the same problem. What resolved this issue for you?